# When to save timezone for user automatically in DB in an optimized manner

Tags: ajax, database, django, django-models

I am writing a `django` application where I have to save the timezone of each user in DB automatically. I have obtained the timezone through javascript and I am doing this in the home page. i.e whenever the homepage is loaded I first find the timezone through javascript, and then make an ajax call to the server with the timezone, and the server would would update the DB if there is any change. This way I would always have the current timezone of a user, but I am thinking would it increase the impact on DB too much or not?

One option I have is to do it only when the user logs in. But in that case the user would be redirected to the page he was before logging in, and I will have to put additional parameters to the redirect URL for the redirect page to decide if it should make the ajax call or not.

Any ideas? My main question here is the first one: would it make any serious impact on the DB?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing it during login. Alongwith the credentials, pass the timezone as well.

If you are using django.contrib.auth, you can get this extra information by writing a custom authentication backend: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/authbackends/

Comment: Thanks, I ended up validating the timezone in client-side. Since client-side already have the user-object, i would check if the new timezone found is different from whats already present, and only then send it to backend